# Are there any paper for a closed domain conversational agent

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, word2vec, word-embeddings

i was trying to find a closed domain conversational agent/chatbot paper in Question and answering so not long conversation, and i don't think i see any.

All the paper i can find are related to an open domain conversational agent or a persona based neural conversational model, etc. I really need this kind of paper since i want to implement a chatbot with a quite niche topic and i can't seem to find any that can help me out.

I search most of the paper from arxiv and this https://github.com/snakeztc/NeuralDialogPapers#task-bots

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated